# Google Calendar webhook repeatedly pushes same notification to flask backend

Tags: python, flask, google-calendar-api, webhooks

I've successfully started watching for changes to my Google Calendar, but it seems as though Google's server is not receiving my success code. After editing my calendar, I continue to get notified several times per minute. (I realize I need to do more to get event info, but I just want to get the webhook working properly first.) What am I missing?

https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/watch

```
@app.route('/cal-check', methods=['POST'])
def cal_check():
    send_schedule_conflict_email(request.get_json(force=True))
    return '', 201
```